# SQL How to remove trailing characters from a field that is causing data to duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Employee table that I need to pull all demographic information from.

The issue is that there is a field called `UNIQUE_ID` that is causing duplicates but SQL does not think there duplicates.

**Explanation**: The `UNIQUE_ID` field contains data like this 'ABCD001' 'ABCD002' ect but then I have the same UNIQUE_ID with characters at the end like this 'ABCD001(ME)' 'ABCD001(ME)(MP)'  'ABCD001(ME)(MP)(UA)'.

So this makes the same employee ABCD001 repeat itself 3 times. I would like to remove those characters at the end to only reflect the ID with out the (ME)(MP)(UA) and appear one time only. Also there can be IDs without the extra characters in parenthesis at the end which is fine or ID's with more than 3 different characters inside the parenthesis like ABCD001(ME)(MP)(UA)(UG)(PB) etc.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Please re-write your question with better formatting to make it easier to read.

Comment: The values you posted are NOT the same. It sounds like you are wanting to take this column which apparently contains two pieces of information and separate them? It is not at all clear what you are really trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    case 
        when idx=0 -- if unique_id doesn't contain brakets
        then UNIQUE_ID  -- then select it
        else LEFT(UNIQUE_ID , idx-1) -- else select substring
    end as UNIQUE_ID_trimmed,
    *
from 
(select 
    *, 
    CHARINDEX('(', UNIQUE_ID,  0) as idx
    from Employee
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Unique_id = SUBSTRING(UNIQUE_ID, 0, CHARINDEX('(', UNIQUE_ID))
FROM Employee
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(UNIQUE_ID, 0, CHARINDEX('(', UNIQUE_ID))
```

You can remove the GROUP BY clause if you want to return dupplicated rows.

Comment: Thanks to all for the examples.